# TCP Stream on Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp

I'm trying to listen on a tcp port that is sending continuous streams of data separated by curly braces { x, y, z}. When I run this script with node, I get the first console output "client connected", but the rest of the script hangs. Is there anything I can do to display the data as it arrives??

```
var s = require('net');

var client = s.connect(2324, '10.12.1.22', function(){
    console.log('client connected');

});

client.on('data', function(d){
      console.log(d);
});
client.end();
```

Comment: because you call `client.end()` before data can be received, you should put `client.end();` inside the `data` event. and I believe you need `s.close()` or `s.end()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are emiting `end` event immediately, which means connection goes down instantly.
In fact you should not emit `end`, TCP Socket is a Stream, it will emit `end` on data end.
Take a look at [`net` module API docs](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html).